# How to fix "Vagarant is not up" error in Windows

Tags: vagrant

Here are my logs when I run `vagrant up` in Windows:

```
There was a problem after restarting the server Launch logs

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/xenial64' version '20190530.3.0' is up to date...
==> default: A newer version of the box 'ubuntu/xenial64' for provider 'virtualbox' is
==> default: available! You currently have version '20190530.3.0'. The latest is version
==> default: '20190731.0.0'. Run `vagrant box update` to update.
C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/version_5_0.rb:593:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/version_5_0.rb:593:in `read_used_ports'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:12:in `call'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:50:in `call'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/before_trigger.rb:23:in `call'        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:50:in `call'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/after_trigger.rb:26:in `call'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:50:in `call'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:50:in `call'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/before_trigger.rb:23:in `call'        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:50:in `call'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/after_trigger.rb:26:in `call'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:50:in `call'
        from C:/Users/dp/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.6/gems/vagrant-hostmanager-1.8.9/lib/vagrant-hostmanager/action/update_all.rb:24:in `call'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:50:in `call'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/before_trigger.rb:23:in `call'        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:50:in `call'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/after_trigger.rb:26:in `call'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:50:in `call'
        from C:/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
```

Comment: It would be easier to read if you could copy the console output and paste it here instead of an image. Clipboard and screen-reader users will also appreciate that.

Comment: Added the console output

Comment: I am run 'vagrant box update' but see the same output in console

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. Please check this:
  https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/9549

You will have this error if you have path to image files of registered VM (inside virtualbox) in non latin alphabet.
That could be image which you NOT start, but it just present in Virtualbox. Inside Virtualbox those VM will just perfectly run. So this problem is not for Virtualbox, but for Vagrant/Ruby.

So current workaround is:

to check ALL images in Virtualbox
and correct all paths which has non-latin/strange symbols. Optionally you could just remove such image.
As mentioned above you could check properties with:

```
VBoxManage list vms
VBoxManage showvminfo <vm-guid> --machinereadable
```